# How to pass a two dimensional list to Treeview (Tkintker)?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I had to create a table that has 19 columns (and any amount of rows) with Treeview. This table
is going to display the results of a query.

The following list for example stores 3 rows of data with 19 columns:

```
query_result=[('Abc', '123', 'aaa'...),('Def', '456', 'bbb'...),('Ghi', '789', 'ccc'...)]
```

I have managed to put these into my table like this, but I believe this is not the smartest way to do it.

```
count_row = 0
for order in query_result:
    table.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count_row, text="", values=(
        query_result[count_row][0],
        query_result[count_row][1],
        query_result[count_row][2],
        query_result[count_row][3],
        query_result[count_row][4],
        query_result[count_row][5],
        query_result[count_row][6],
        query_result[count_row][7],
        query_result[count_row][8],
        query_result[count_row][9],
        query_result[count_row][10],
        query_result[count_row][11],
        query_result[count_row][12],
        query_result[count_row][13],
        query_result[count_row][14],
        query_result[count_row][15],
        query_result[count_row][16],
        query_result[count_row][17],
        query_result[count_row][18]))
    count_row += 1
```

Is there any other way to pass all of the data without having to add a line for each column?

Comment: Try `values=query_result[count_row]`

Comment: Oh my god the amount of time I have wasted for figuring this out...thank you very much.

Comment: Basically when you use `(query_result[count_row][0], query_result[count_row][1], ...)` you create a tuple like this: `("Abc", "123", "aaa"...)`. So to simplify it I just used the tuple that already exists.